# why am i getting attribute error "AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'interface'"

Tags: python, object, attributes

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 12, in 
    interface = options.interface
AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'interface'

```
import subprocess
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest=" interface ", help=" Interface to change its MAC address ")

parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest=" mac ", help=" new mac address ")

(options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()

interface = options.interface
mac = options.mac

print("[+] Changing mac address for " + interface + " to " + mac)

subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, " down"])

subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, " hw", "ether", mac])

subprocess.call(["ifconfig ", interface, " up"])
```

Note:- i am using virtualBox to run this program.

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message in your question.

Answer (score 2):

`dest` parameter of `add_option` defines the member of the `Values` object. You used a name with leading & trailing spaces. This defines members with spaces in it, not reachable by classical field access.

To debug it just do:

```
print(dir(options))
```

this prints:

```
[' interface ', ' mac ', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', … other members ...]
```

Remove the spaces and you'll be able to access `interface` and `mac`:

```
parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help=" Interface to change its MAC address ")
parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="mac", help=" new mac address ")
```